# Change home-url in dashboard

Tags: admin, admin-bar

I am wondering if I can change the URL of the "Home"-button in the dashboard's admin-bar.

[image]

Right now it just redirects to `/`, but I need it to redirect to `/velkommen`.

Whenever a logged-in user lands on `/`, they are already redirected to `/velkommen`, so in a way it's already working as I want (with an extra redirect), but it would be nice to prevent having to run that javascript redirect, also because it creates waiting time for the user.

I tried the following things, to now luck:

[Change homepage url](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190183/change-homepage-url/190185#190185)

[How to change the Admin-bar's link target?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42442/how-to-change-the-admin-bars-link-target)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.
Even if you want to change "View Site" link then remove "site-name" and add "view-site" in get_node.
Thanks.

```
 add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'customize_my_wp_admin_bar', 80 );
 function customize_my_wp_admin_bar( $wp_admin_bar ) {
        $site_node = $wp_admin_bar->get_node('site-name');

        //Change link
        $site_node->href = home_url().'/velkommen';

        //Update Node.
        $wp_admin_bar->add_node($site_node);

 }
```

Comment: Awesome, it worked! Shaved a few ms off of our customer's flow :)

Comment: @Rvervuurt awesome! enjoy.